# How to protect a file in Windows

Tags: windows, file-permissions, file-access

**Update 3:** the restrict access, using the security tab works now. (that's manually)
now looking to do it programatically (using Visual C#) and also how to access a file using administrator account in a simple user account.
hint - I noticed this feature in Windows, right click and use 'Execute as', enter the administrator password and then you can access the file.

**Update 2:** Found how to display the security tab

> To display the Security tab
>
> Open Folder Options in Control Panel.
>   (Click Start, click Control Panel,
>   click Appearance and Themes, and then
>   click Folder Options.)
>
> On the View tab, under Advanced
>   settings, clear Use simple file
>   sharing [Recommended].

**Update 1:** I found the following [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456977.aspx), which suggests how to give permissions to files, however I don't find the security tab when I click properties, do you have it? Any ideas how to get it

I have a file that I want to protect from bein modified.
Don't say to me encrypt it, this don't solve the problem, I want that users can't change the file, BUT only me (my program).
Is there any type of authentication for Windows files, I know that what I say is stupid about authentication, but some Windows files are inaccessible like 'ntuser.dat.LOG' in the user profile. When I try to open this file it doesn't open.

I want something like that, for this file it seems because Windows is using it. Right.
But what about if my program shutdown, I don't want the file to be changed in this case also.
How shall i do?

I don't ask for the complete detailed solution, I want ideas, suggestions, tips, or any thing you know that it'll help, as it seems to be complicated :p

Comment: If you're missing the security tab, then it's probably because the file is on a FAT/FAT32 file system. The security tab is only valid when the file resides on the NTFS file system.

Comment: WHY don't you want the file to be changed? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @petesh found a resolution
@adam looking to protect a file from noisy childs :p

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Why can't you just run the app as an admin user, and lock down the kid's account?

Comment: that's currently what I want to do.
The application will be used on an administrator account and the kids account will be locked from accessing the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on a Windows domain, or just a workgroup?  What version of Windows is this?  Are you an administrator of the computer?

You should be able to take ownership of a file, and then set the permissions so that you're the only one that can access that file.  On Windows XP (Vista is similar) Right-click on the file and view `Properties`. Select the `Security` tab and then you can set specific permissions on a file.  You can click `Advanced` and set even more specific options.

If you're on a domain, the domain administrators will always be able to view/edit any of your files.

Edit:
From [KB 290403](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290403):

> In Windows XP Home Edition and Windows XP Professional, if working in a workgroup, the Security tab is hidden by default. This behavior occurs because in Windows XP Home Edition and Windows XP Professional, guests are forced to log on to a workgroup.

So if you want to pursue this, you can boot your computer into Safe mode and then you'll see the `Security` tab.

You can also uncheck `Simple file sharing` in the `Advanced` options.

Comment: I don't see the security tab, anything wrong? I use XP Pro
no the computer is not on a domain nor a workgroup, it's an alone computer

Answer (score 1):

you can run a windows service that locks the files or something

Comment: your idea is interesting, you mean like how Windows is looking his own files.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution that worked well for you?  I like this solution because of how easy it would be to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Revoke access for all users but yourself (or the account that the program is running as).
Right-click in Windows Explorer, Properties, Security.

Comment: not the account! The program should run within the same account as the user

Answer (score 0):

Idea, then: modify your file so that only one user can have access to it. Remove all other users permissions. Run your application as a service authenticated with the only user who has access to the file.

Comment: I have seen something like this in Vista, but not in Xp.
Is it possible in XP and how?

Comment: In fact it's possible since Windows NT. :-) NTFS lets you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change de rights of the file to make is owner a user created by your application at installation time. But anyway an administrator car override this, i can't see a way to succesfully lock it.

Even a windows service can be shutdown, there will be no absolute solution as far as I can see.

Comment: No solution is perfect, however if i don't lock the file, any stupid can change it, if i lock with a service, so it'll be more complicated 'What locks the file' for Tech-Savvy. Especially my app is for them

Answer (score 0):

The file would have to be owned by the SYSTEM user and only have read rights given to the regular USERS group.

Your installer should be able to create the file, give full control to system, then eliminate local user rights to it.  Except for the right to read.

Comment: That's a good idea, now what about the application how can it access the file?

Comment: Assuming the application runs under the currently logged in user, it should have read capability to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an MD5 or similar hash using the file's contents. When reopening the file, check the stored hash to make sure that the file hasn't changed.

Comment: LOL this is my subjective so far, checking if it was changed or not don't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea! May be not very useful!

Restrict permission to the file (This is common) and make sure only your porgram has access to it. BUt this is not fail proof as the admin user can change the security of the file.

Read the first n bytes or some random bytes and store it in the registry. Next time when your program starts check whether the bytes match if not the file was changed. If so you try to recreate the file.

Comment: That's what I'm searching on, for the moment; checking if the file was changed is useless... I don't want to know if it's changed, I just want to secure it.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done!

Sorry for this blunt answer, but despite any suggested software measure to "protect" the file, it will not help.

If the user really wants to access the file, he can simply insert the hard disk into another computer and modify the file. Or she can use a Linux live CD that runs independent of the installed operating system.

Comment: With NTFS encryption turned on in Windows, the file will only be readable by the user who created it. Not much luck on another computer or from Linux.

Comment: Delete it, then write it new. It might be unencrypted then, but it is changed. Encryption is only a solution to prevent data from being read.

Answer (score 0):

Sign the file with a private key embedded in your application, and check the signature before loading the file. You'll have to re-sign every time you write the file so that the signature reflects any changes (if the file is modified without being signed, it will be obvious when you try to load the file).

NB this isn't totally secure. A cracker could conceivably extract the key from your application, and use it to sign his modified version of the file. It doesn't protect against a malicious attack, but will keep your average user from modifying the file.

EDIT: Hmm, seems you don't care about DETECTING if the file is modified, you want to actually PREVENT the file from being modified. Sorry, I don't think there is a way to do this. The user could easily kill off any process "locking" the file, or even boot up with a Live CD or something and edit the file that way.

Comment: precaution is better than nothing
not all users can do that, IF %60 of my users are tech-savvy, so at least I prevented %60

Answer (score 0):

Dare I say it... "[NTFS Alternate Data Streams](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763)" - please don't shoot me!

Yes their easy to modify, but not easily located by your average junkie.

Answer (score 0):

*Because most versions of Windows don't embrace a way of password protective your files and folders, this page provides steps on encrypting files and folders instead. To password shield your files and folders in Windows, you would like to use a third-party program.*

**Microsoft Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 10 users**

Unfortunately, Windows vista, Windows 7,  Windows 8 and windows 10 don't offer any options for password protective files or folders. you would like to use a third-party software package program to accomplish this.
If you would like to encode a file or folder, this may be done by following these steps:

1. Choose the file or folder you would like to encode.
2. Right-click the file or folder and choose Properties.
3. On the general tab, click the Advanced button.
4. Check the box for the "Encrypt contents to secure data" choice.
5. Click Apply then OK.

**Microsoft Windows XP Professional users**

The steps below for encrypting the files on Windows XP professional apply to users who are using a laptop that has 2 or a lot of accounts. If you're using a single account, see the opposite security solutions section.

1. Choose the file or folder you would like to encode.
2. Right-click the file or folder and click on Properties.
3. On the general tab, click the Advanced button.
4. Check "Encrypt contents to secure data" choice.
5. Click Apply then OK.

**Microsoft Windows XP Home users**

1. Choose the file or folder you would like to encode.
2. Right-click the file or folder and click on Properties.
3. Click the Sharing tab.
4. Check the box make this folder private
5. Click Apply then OK.

To learn more about this topic go to [cryptography in windows](http://goutamaman.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-to-protect-files-with-cryptography_54.html)

***Source*** :-
[Technology](http://goutamaman.blogspot.in)